# Python script to reboot server N times

Tags: linux, stress-testing

I'm trying to stress test several servers that I can ssh into. I'm trying to write a python script that causes a reboot loop for N times. I call

```
os.system('reboot')
```

But, I'm not sure how to have the script continue execution once the server has finished booting to continue execution. The servers do run various distros of Linux. Any help would be great.

Comment: cron http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab

Comment: Question: Do you *have* to involve python in this? Or would any solution work?

Comment: Really stress them out by reboot upon ssh connection continuously

Comment: I guess any solution would work. I'm just used to python so that's what I chose.

Comment: Unless you do something to start up the process and read from some stored statefile (e.g. a file on disk), this is not something you could do on the server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the solution doesn't have to be in Python, so you can just use a Bash script for this (given that you can ping the server):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
COUNTER=$1
SERVER=$2
COMMAND="sudo reboot"
SLEEP_DURATION=60

echo "Working on $SERVER $COUNTER times"

while (( $COUNTER > 0 )); do
    ping -c 1 -t 5 $SERVER;
    _ping_r=$?
    if (( $_ping_r < 1 )); then
        echo "Rebooting $SERVER"
        ssh $SERVER $COMMAND;
        let COUNTER=COUNTER-1
    else
        echo "Couldn't ping $SERVER.  Taking a quick nap and trying again."
        sleep 5
    fi
    sleep $SLEEP_DURATION;
done

echo "Done working on $SERVER"
```

Save it in something like `command_runner.sh` and simply call it via `./command_runner.sh 2 server.example.org` on a workstation that can SSH and run reboot on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use `Fabric` to ssh into several servers in parallel and to execute various commands there](http://www.fabfile.org/) (even those commands that require reboot -- you might need to disconnect all servers explicitly in your `fabfile.py` after such commands).